# CloudSolrServer, graceful shutdown

Tags: solr, solrj

I was reading this PDF: http://2010.lucene-eurocon.org/slides/Solr-In-The-Cloud_Mark-Miller.pdf, and there is a section that talks about `CloudSolrServer`. In particular, this statement is made:

> It keeps a list of both live and dead servers. When a request to a server fails, that server is added to the ‘dead’ list, and another ‘live’ server is queried instead.
>   The ‘dead’ server list is occasionally pinged, and if a server comes back, it is moved back into the ‘live’ list.

This works fine when a SOLR instance or the machine crashes, but for normal maintenance it would be undesirable because requests in progress would be lost. Typically with a normal load balancer, there's a way to shut off traffic to a box, and then normal shutdown can proceed at some interval after that.

Since it appears that CloudSolrServer is intended to replace a traditional load balancer in front of a SOLR cluster, I was wondering about graceful shutdown. What is the recommended way to shutdown a SOLR instance while not losing requests, (while using CloudSolrServer)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gracefully shutdown an instance, you will need to first remove the corresponding node from  ZooKeeper and then shut down the instance. You can remove the node from ZK by using "DELETEREPLICA" command:

> /admin/collections?action=DELETEREPLICA&collection=collection&shard=shard&replica=replica

[See more in Solr Collections API documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api9)

once the ephemeral node is removed from ZooKeeper, CloudSolrServer will stop sending requests to it.